# Document in Development server is not opening which were copied from production db.Lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I copy pasted some document from production server db to Dev server db , but when I tried to open any of these document then its giving error like ...The server with this database is no longer responding , should notes switch to a replica or another server ...whether old documents are opening fine in the Dev database.

Any suggestion appreciable...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is going to be in the design of your application. You'll have to figure this one out on your own.

For example:

Does this record have computed or static fields (or formulas) pointing to the production server?

Does the form for the record use the 'unid' in one of the calculated fields (possibly as a key)? If so, you will get a broken key following the paste, since the last saved unid value would no longer match the actual doc unid.

Does your record have any other dependency records, that you also need to copy over?

Does your record have references (such as @DbLookups) to missing configuration records in your dev system (such as "keyword" lists or "system documents/profiles")?

Good luck